# How do I center fluid divs that also have max-widths?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

Consider the following setup :

CSS :

```
#container {
   position: relative;
   width: 95%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 100%;
}

.parent {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   float: left;
   clear: left;
}    

.child {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
   max-width: 200px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div class="parent">
         <div class="child"></div>
         <div class="child"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="parent">
         <div class="child"></div>
         <div class="child"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
<body>
```

If the width of the window is greater than 400px, the `.child` elements will not be centered but will rather stick to the left.

I can't know the number of `.child` elements in advance (but the number inside each parent will always be the same across all `.parent` elements). If there's more I use JS to calculate and assign new percentages to their widths anyway so they still remain responsive (So if I have 2 child elements their widths will be 50%, if I have four their widths will be 25% etc..).

Is there a way keep the `.child` elements centered with the above setup ?

Thank you for your help in advance. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-align: center` to the `.parent`, remove the `float` and change the `display` property to `inline-block` on the child.

```
.parent {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   float: left;
   clear: left;
   text-align: center;
}    

.child {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 50%;
   max-width: 200px;
}
```

If the space between items is an issue, split the ending tags on the child divs:

```
<div class="child"></div
><div class="child"></div>
```

le CodePen: http://codepen.io/erquhart/pen/ukHco